# SSRS 2008 R2 - Axes with Format M 25, T 26, etc

Tags: charts, axes, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using SSRS to produce a Gantt Chart. In my header I have a chart with the axis visible, but no series data, then each row has an embedded chart showing it's timeline

The last image on this page shows it: http://marcjellinek.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/how-to-create-a-gantt-like-chart-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

the horizontal axes is date and my users want it to display

M 21, T 22, W 23, T 24, etc.

Normally I could just cast to a string and get the parts I want (e.g. LEFT(FORMAT(Field..., "ddd"),1) or something like that) and then concat the bits I need; however, I have no field in an axes number format. I managed to get following using a format of dd ddd

Mon 21, Tues 22, Wed 23, etc.

Anyone got any ideas?

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not going to be able to accomplish this using only the Chart dialog, because it will only accept numeric entries for the label. However, if you assign numeric labels (such as the day of the month) that will line up the data in the desired order, you can then add labels outside of the chart area (such as inside a tablix) that will populate right below the chart and look like they're in the exact right spot. Here are the steps as I see them to accomplish your desired solution:

1. In the dataset where you are returning all of the data for the chart, add an additional field named "Label". The Label field should contain whatever text you would like to display in the label field (e.g., "T 22").
2. Hide the chart's labels and the corresponding Axis Title. This puts the bottom of the chart's horizontal axis several points from the bottom of the Chart area.
3. Create a tablix with a column group that is grouped on the Label field.
4. Then, in the details column of this new tablix, have it insert the Label field.
5. Set the WritingMode property for each cell to "Vertical" and adjust the spacing to line up with where the true labels should be residing on the chart.
6. Align the tablix with the chart, leaving 0pts of space between the two, that way the tablix will always be rendered directly below the chart.

There will end up being a small gap between the axis and the labels, but most end-users would never question it.

Hopefully, this makes sense to you. If any part of it doesn't, please reply with a comment asking your question.

Comment: @Cristopher brown. Thanks for reply Chris. I'll give it a try and see if it works.